# HTML redirect with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Working on a website that uses Ajax - http://jasonanarchy.com

I'm trying to get the boxes that hold the images to redirect to their respective websites. (the domains that show when you hover)

Here is the code to one of the box elements:

```
<a href="http://anarchyplants.com" class="element element-portfolio portfolio ajax">
        <input type="hidden" class="order" value="2">
        <img src="/img/portfolio/aplants.jpg" class="portfolio-image" alt="portfolio image"/>
        <span class="portfolio-title"><i class="icon-play"></i>Anarchy Plants
        </span>
    </a>
```

My guess is the "Element" call is what makes the box do it's funky ajax thing, but if I remove it, it breaks the box. What would I have to change/edit to get it to work?

I want to keep all elements of the ajax, but have it so when you click it, you actually go to anarchyplants.com

AJAX CLICK LINK:

```
/* 
     * Ajax link click (mainly for portfolio items but any content can be linked to) 
     */

     $('.ajax').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var page = $(this).attr('href');
         $('.container-footer').fadeOut(199);
         $('.last-scroll').val($(document).scrollTop());    //current scroll posn to return to later
         $('html').append('<img src="img/loading.gif" class="load-gif" style="z-index: 999"/>');
         $('.load-gif').css({
                position:'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() - $('.load-gif').outerWidth())/2,
                top: ($(window).height() - $('.load-gif').outerHeight())/2
            });
         $('#container-isotope').fadeOut(200, function(){
         $.get(page, function(data) {
              $('.load-gif').remove();
              $('.ajax-content').html(data);
              $('#container-isotope').stop().hide();
              $('.container-footer').fadeIn(599);
              $('#container-ajax').fadeIn(600, function(){
                  $('.close-ajax').show();
              });
              window.scrollTo(0,0);
            }); 
         });
     });

     $('.close-ajax').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).hide();
        $('.container-footer').fadeOut(199);
        $('#container-ajax').fadeOut(200,function(){
            $('#container-isotope').fadeIn(600);
            $('.container-footer').fadeIn(599);
            window.scrollTo(0,$('.last-scroll').val());
            $container.isotope();
            $('#container-ajax .ajax-content').html("");
        });
     });
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated! - Cheers!~

Comment: At the bottom of your page, you have the script (Commented by 'Ajax Link Click') ... I would just remove that. It's that script that has changed all  `a href` links to try load into the page itself, but can't because the cross-origin request is being blocked.

Comment: Aha! I see what you're talking about and the parameters within it - There is a lot there. What specifically should be taken out to allow redirects without the ajax page? - Ill add the code to my edit.

Comment: It's long, so I'll put it as an answer. Test every other link on the page after though, because I'm not sure if the functions are being used else where.

Comment: Oh all of it! - I removed that entire sequence just to check, and the redirects now work. THANK YOU! - Post as an answer so that I may upvote you kind sir.

Comment: No problems, anytime :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from the `<script>` section at the bottom of the page:

```
/* 
     * Ajax link click (mainly for portfolio items but any content can be linked to) 
     */

     $('.ajax').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var page = $(this).attr('href');
         $('.container-footer').fadeOut(199);
         $('.last-scroll').val($(document).scrollTop());    //current scroll posn to return to later
         $('html').append('<img src="img/loading.gif" class="load-gif" style="z-index: 999"/>');
         $('.load-gif').css({
                position:'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() - $('.load-gif').outerWidth())/2,
                top: ($(window).height() - $('.load-gif').outerHeight())/2
            });
         $('#container-isotope').fadeOut(200, function(){
         $.get(page, function(data) {
              $('.load-gif').remove();
              $('.ajax-content').html(data);
              $('#container-isotope').stop().hide();
              $('.container-footer').fadeIn(599);
              $('#container-ajax').fadeIn(600, function(){
                  $('.close-ajax').show();
              });
              window.scrollTo(0,0);
            }); 
         });
     });

     $('.close-ajax').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).hide();
        $('.container-footer').fadeOut(199);
        $('#container-ajax').fadeOut(200,function(){
            $('#container-isotope').fadeIn(600);
            $('.container-footer').fadeIn(599);
            window.scrollTo(0,$('.last-scroll').val());
            $container.isotope();
            $('#container-ajax .ajax-content').html("");
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the href tag:

```
target="_top"

or

target="_blank"
```

Comment: Where in the href to be exact? 

        <a href="http://anarchyplants.com" class="element element-portfolio portfolio ajax" target="_blank">

Comment: Won't this just pop the link in a new window?